# Trying to populate my user model and getting a Type Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my program I want to populate my index page with a model called a group. Previously I just showed all the groups that existed in the database, but now I want to only show the groups that the user who is logged in is associated with.

Here are the models:
Group Model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var groupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: String,
    thumbnail: String,
    description: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    },
    inviteCode: String,
    images: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Image"

        }
    ],
    users: [
        {
           type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: "User"
        }
    ] });

module.exports = mongoose.model("Group", groupSchema);
```

User Model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    groups: 
        [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, //referencing model by id
                ref: "Group" //name of the model
            }
        ],
    images: 
        [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, //referencing model by id
                ref: "Image" //name of the model
            }
        ]
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose); //add in local mongoose methods to user

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

My Index Route:

```
//Index Route
router.get("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    var user = req.user;
    user.populate("groups").exec(function(err, allGroups){ 
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           res.render("groups/show", {groups: allGroups});
           console.log(allGroups);
       }
   });
});
```

And this is the error I get:

> TypeError: user.populate(...).exec is not a function

I am not sure why I cant use the populate method with my user model, can someone explain me an alternative to achieve the desired outcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that req.user is not a schema, so .populate is not a method carried by that variable in its object prototype. Hence the terminal telling you it's not a function.

You have to require the User schema like this in your index route:

```
const User = require("./models/user");
```

Then find the user by its id then populate it:

```
//Index Route
    router.get("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
        var user = req.user;
        User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, foundUser) {
            let user = foundUser;
            user.populate("groups").exec(function(err, allGroups){ 
               if(err){
                   console.log(err);
               } else {
                   res.render("groups/show", {groups: allGroups});
                   console.log(allGroups);
               }
           });
        });
    });
```

Let me know if it works!